# Accessing BigQuery on Google App Engine dev server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am successfully able to get BQ data from one project to another from the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212991/how-to-query-bigquery-programmatically-from-python-without-end-user-interaction) answer. However this only works when deployed on my development/staging instance and not my local development server on Google App Engine.

My findings are that it works in production because you include:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```

in app.yaml. However these libraries are not accessible from the dev server. I have tried installing everything locally (Pycrypto, oauth2client, openSSL) after digging through some docs and tracing the error but still cannot get it to work. I have tried installing through pip and manually doing the build/install from the raw files to no avail. Any advice on getting these queries to work on the local django server? Working on Ubuntu if that matters, perhaps it's looking in the wrong spot for the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just the libs that are mising follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11405769/3877822 to insatll pycrypto to the root of your project

> As @Udi suggests in the comment below, the following command also
> installs pycrypto and can be used in virtualenv as well:
>
> easy_install
> http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe
>
> Notice to choose the relevant link for your setup from [this list](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/)

Comment: Wouldn't this be redundant by including the lib folder as well as including it in app.yaml for whatever deployed environment?

Comment: If its just for the local dev it wont be an issue. You can use the skip files directive in the app.yaml to not upload it. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files